# Change request: gray out review button if already reviewed

Tags: feature-request, documentation, review-queues

In the `proposedchanges/need review` (for instance https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python?tab=proposedchanges) tab all proposed changes* have a `Review` button, so I can't tell which are the ones I've already reviewed.

(*) except for my own

EDIT: question has been made obsolete by the new rewiew system ([FYI - New Documentation Review Queue for Proposed Changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334300/fyi-new-documentation-review-queue-for-proposed-changes))

Comment: I guess you and the upvoters know, but I can't figure out what you're talking about.  Where is that tab?

Comment: @Teepeemm go to http://stackoverflow.com/documentation click on your favorite tag e.g http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android from there click on "dashboard" and then on "proposed changes" and you'll se a list of changes that need review