# FYI - New Documentation Review Queue for Proposed Changes

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues

In a few minutes, we'll be turning on a new [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) for documentation's proposed changes, detailed in [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th).

This is just a heads-up to let everyone know to report bugs here or tag them with [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation)[review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) - there will be a more detailed announcement next week.

Thanks!

Comment: 2.3K items pending review.  Reminds me of the early days with the Close Vote queue.

Comment: We can do it! Suggested edits queue does it [all the time](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/537413/last-100-days-of-suggested-edit-counts#graph) :)

Comment: Is there a possibility to "Improve Edit" as in "Suggested Edits"?

Comment: @Unheilig yes, improving is planned.

Comment: Is it possible we can get a stats page along with this queue, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats? Obviously not a high priority, but I'm just curious.

Comment: @hichris123:  Worth making a feature request post for, honestly...

Comment: @Makoto Wrote one up: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334306/have-a-stats-page-for-new-documentation-review-queue.

Comment: I don't think the Suggested Edits queue is a good example. The way it gets emptied "all the time" is because it has an appalling amount of robo-reviewers.

Comment: Shouldn't this post get the [tag:featured] tag?

Comment: I like the idea of a proper review queue, but my worry is that reviews won't be so thorough any more. It seems like it will just lead to people superficially reviewing topics that they aren't an expert in just to clear the queue, whereas previously you had to go out of your way to review a different topic, so you tended to get subject experts reviewing more strictly.

Comment: There's a limit of thirty reviews? Seems kind of low.

Comment: @JarrodDixon [tag:featured]?

Comment: I see no way to get to the actual page from the review page.  I want this because I want to make a minor edit to a freshly Approved page.

Comment: @RickJames Just click on the title in the edits.

Comment: Not going to tag this [tag:featured], as another post will discuss it in more detail next week.

Comment: Huge kudos to whomever (plural?) worked on this. The raw performance (as in load time for reviews) is awesome.

Comment: Needs the style of the other review queues.

Comment: Disagree, @RamenChef. The other queues need the style of this one.