# Have a 'stats' page for new Documentation review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, documentation, review-queues

Every other review queue has a stats page, for example https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats. It's nice to use to keep track of recent reviews, how many people are actively reviewing, and what the size of the queue is. However, the new Documentation queue doesn't have this page. Could a stats page be added for this queue?