# Why am I getting rep for doc changes I had nothing to do with?

Tags: support, documentation, reputation, reputation-history

Today I received `+2` rep for a doc change 4 different times, on topics I have contributed nothing to. You can see this [in my reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3524982/djmcmayhem?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2016-09-09%2020:53:14Z). Each one of these is from an edit (that I did not suggest) being accepted on a topic I have contributed almost nothing to.

The only thing I can think of, is that maybe I'm getting this rep because I was the person who initially proposed the [pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pygame) docs page. Is this correct? Is this by design?

If this is design, I fail to see why I deserve to gain rep for someone else contributing to a topic that I happened to create (especially since I have contributed almost nothing else to the topic).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Each of those topics were ones you requested:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/93472?noredirect=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/80045?noredirect=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/77633?noredirect=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/69074?noredirect=1

The +2 reputation from a topic you requested getting created is not explicitly listed in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). I believe it's implied by the line:

> - proposed change is approved: +2

I don't believe this is new, but since [the review queue was introduced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334300/1438), many improvement requests have been approved.

Comment: I completely forgot about requesting those topics since it was so long ago. Well now I feel like an idiot. Thanks for clarifying this for me!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem: The fault is mostly on us. It should never take more than a month for proposed changes to be reviewed. (On the other hand, this is why we have betas. ;-)