# Why Did I Get Reputation From This Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

I noticed I got a +2 rep boost from [this Documentation post.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/97764)  I don't see my username on it anywhere and I'm having a really difficult time remembering what, if anything, I contributed.  Am I just not looking in the right place to see what I did?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer as I am not 100% sure, but pretty sure I saw a post somewhere saying that the poster of a topic request gets rep when the topic is successfully created. [You posted the topic request](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/topic-requests/147) that that specific topic was created from.

Comment: @Kendra - How were you able to find that I was the requester of the topic?

Comment: Go to the dashboard of the tag. Under "Requested Topics" click the "handled" tab. Yours is the first one listed there at the moment. And I found the post I was thinking of: [Why am I getting rep for doc changes I had nothing to do with?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334388/why-am-i-getting-rep-for-doc-changes-i-had-nothing-to-do-with)

Comment: @Kendra - Ah, okay.  That's a good enough answer for me; if you want to post it as one, I'll accept it.